# openCV with visual studio, link error

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013

Trying to run OpenCV with Visual studio but I got the following link error

```
Error   error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_nonfree2411d.lib'   opencv_contrib  LINK    
Error   error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_ocl2411d.lib'   opencv_nonfree  LINK
```

What can be the problem and how can I solve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linker issue in opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675192/linker-issue-in-opencv)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the linker can not find the *.lib Files it needs.
To solve this add the path to the *.lib files to your Projects properties under

> "Linker | General | Additonal Library Directories"

for all Configurations (Release, Debug etc.).

There is a detailed explanation about how to get OpenCv running in the [official docs](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html).